# C# - XNA; I don't understand how making classes interact works

Tags: c#, xna

If I had 3 .cs files; Game1.cs, Player.cs, and HUD.cs; with Game1 being the master class, Player.cs storing Player_Main, Player_Sprite, Player_Movement classes etc, and HUD.cs containing any HUD related variables and controlling the drawing of the HUD to the screen, how do I make the Player_Whatever classes use variables from each other, and then have the Player_Main act as kind of the holding class where it passes everything done in the other classes to the master class for drawing+updating etc?

If I need to add or reword anything let me know, still new to both C# and this website.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question to be asking. I would recommend that you look into different XNA 4.0 tutorials to help you get a feel for game design using XNA. I've included a few good ones below.

http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/series2d.php

http://xnagpa.net/tutorials.php

http://xnaresources.com/default.asp?page=TUTORIALS

http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/xna-tutorials

Personally when I started to learn XNA I had the most success with RB Whitaker's Tutorial Series as well as the tutorial series on XNAResources.com

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be too broad. I've just looked everywhere and just can't find a tutorial that I can understand and make sense of about how to use variables in other classes easily.
But thank you I will take a look at these ones.

Comment: I think you might want to look less at a C#/XNA tutorial and more on an object oriented programming tutorial.

Comment: You might be right, have any on hand to link? If not I'll go searching.